# Home screen shortcut wont add

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I am trying to add a short on home screen programmatically but it wont work. 
The code works for Oreo and above but not below that.

```
public void addShortcutToHomeScreen() {

        if (ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(this)) {

            ShortcutInfoCompat shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(this, "#1")
                    .setIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityMemes.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) //!!! intent's action must be set on oreo
                    .setShortLabel("Memeify")
                    .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .build();
            ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(this, shortcutInfo, null);

        } else {

            Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Activity.class);

            shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

            Intent addIntent = new Intent();
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Name");
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

            addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

        }
    }
```

Here is my Manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.my.package.Activities.Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Please, Tell me what am I doing wrong cause I have tried to fixed it and have failed. And is there any better way than this? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**EDIT :**

Found this in the Logcat.

```
2019-01-16 13:27:46.773 735-13377/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT flg=0x10 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } from com.chameleon.memeify (pid=14824, uid=10300) requires com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT due to receiver com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.home.InstallShortcutReceiver
```

Comment: anything in the logcat?

Comment: Added the Logcat.

Comment: don't you see that `requires com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`?

Comment: Now I got it, Thanks.

Comment: I thought I had added it. Didn't knew I was so stupid to miss such an obvious thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method in your application class

```
public void createShortCut() {

            Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
            Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.logo);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class));
            sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);

        }
    }
```

and apply this permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Was missing the permission, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your are on Android 8+ you can't use the broadcast anymore and you have to use the ShortcutManager : 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#as

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) includes the following changes to app shortcuts:
>
> - The com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT broadcast no longer has any effect on your app, because it is now a private, implicit broadcast. Instead, you should create an app shortcut by using the requestPinShortcut() method from the ShortcutManager class.
> - The ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT intent can now create app shortcuts that you manage using the ShortcutManager class. This intent can also create legacy launcher shortcuts that don't interact with ShortcutManager. Previously, this intent could create only legacy launcher shortcuts.
> - Shortcuts created using requestPinShortcut() and shortcuts created in an activity that handles the ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT intent are now fully-fledged app shortcuts. As a result, apps can now update them using the methods in ShortcutManager.
> - Legacy shortcuts retain their functionality from previous versions of Android, but you must convert them to app shortcuts manually in your app.
>     To learn more about changes to app shortcuts, see the [Pinning Shortcuts and Widgets feature guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts#pinning).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.